# Can I add to a 1:many list without reading/saving the parent object?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following Event object (event is a party, not calling a method in this use):

```
public class Event 
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    // lots more properties

    public Recurrence? Recurrence { get; set; }
}

public class Recurrence
{
    // lots more properties

    public Event? RecurrencePatternEvent { get; set; }

    public List<Event>? RecurrenceInstances { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new `Event` object, it has the `Event.Recurrence` object created and populated. When this happens there is also a `pattern` Event that is assigned to `RecurrencePatternEvent`.

This part is no problem. I am creating a new `Event` with its `Recurrence` property I assign `@event.Recurrence.RecurrencePatternEvent = pattern;`. There is no possibility of an update conflict because this is inserting a new object. And if the related `pattern` object is deleted just before the save, then I do want a DbUpdateConcurrencyException or other exception because it is now impossible to add this object. All good.

However, I also need to add this new event to `pattern.Recurrence.RecurrenceInstances`. This means in terms of actual database I/O, I just need this added to the join table that represents this list. Is there a way to directly do this?

If I have to read pattern, add to that property, and then save, I now have the possibility of update conflicts as multiple users may be adding an event to the parent pattern. Logically this update conflict is unnecessary, but the way EF works, as I understand it, I have this problem.

Is it possible I can define the `RecurrencePatternEvent` / `RecurrenceInstances` relationship so that saving `Recurrence.RecurrencePatternEvent` then with no action on my part adds the pait to the join table for `RecurrenceInstances`?

And if EF does not have a way, is their any downside to my making direct ADO.NET calls for this one situation. And if so, is there a way to have both the save the new event object via EF and the ADO.NET join table addition, in the same transaction?